# How to use a Time Capsule as a wireless bridge?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, time-machine

I have a broadband router downstairs which I can connect to using WiFi.

I would like to use a Time Capsule as an ethernet bridge.

So basically, the Time Capsule would connect to the existing wireless network and I want to be able to connect devices via an ethernet cable to the Time Capsule, e.g. an xBox and a NAS.

The xBox should then be able to go online through the Time Capsule and the router's wireless network.

Is this possible?

Comment: I was looking for screenshots of airport utility to see if it had that option, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible with the Time Capsule.

It can join another network as a wireless client, but that mode only allows its local services -- file sharing (backup) and printer sharing -- to be accessed; it can't bridge Ethernet frames in that mode.

If your downstairs Wi-Fi router was an AirPort Extreme/Express/Time Capsule, then you'd be able to have the upstairs Time Capsule "Extend the Network" of the downstairs device, but this mode is only supported when both ends are Apple base station products.

The 802.11n AirPort Express is the only Apple base station that can do what you need -- join a third-party Wi-Fi router as a client, and still bridge traffic to/from its Ethernet port.

Comment: Ah, tricky. Nice to know.